# Launcher icon blury in Kindle carousel

Tags: android, icons, kindle-fire

I am just testing my Android 4+ on a Kindle Fire. Most things work fine but the launcher icon that is displayed in the Carousel is very blury. I think the reason for this is quite obvious:

The Kindle system expects some large versions of the icon:

```
Kindle Fire HDX 8.9" (3rd Gen)   624 x 624
Kindle Fire HDX 7" (3rd Gen)     562 x 562
Kindle Fire HD 7" (3rd Gen)      375 x 375
Kindle Fire HD 8.9" (2nd Gen)    675 x 675
Kindle Fire HD 7" (2nd Gen)      425 x 425
Kindle Fire (2nd Gen)            365 x 365
Kindle Fire (1st Gen)            322 x 322
```

If the system looks for these sizes the best fit it the 192x192 xxxhdpi version of the launcher icon which is this than scaled up. That the result is blury is not a big suprise.

The Question is how I can add the additional sizes of the icon to the app? The Kindle sizes are no standard sizes for the Launcher icon. Is there some kind of naming convention or a special folder within the app I have to place the files in?

Comment: if you sideload the apk then it will only pick up the icon that's in the package. when you publish through the developer portal it will then pick up the assets that you supply when yo upload

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Problem is: The Developer Portal does not offer any possibility to upload such files. It only uses SmallIcon (114x114), LargeIcon(512x512), Screenshots (different sizes), TV Screenshots and Promotional image (1014x500). There are no other upload fields for icons the the sizes in question (624, 562, 375, ...)